# Split a Landscape Page into 4 Parts

Tags: landscape

I wish to divide a landscape page into 4 blocks, as shown below. The top two blocks contain verses with the line numbers on the side, and the two blocks on the bottom contains the meaning.

Here's the template that I'm using for the landscape book : https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/landscape-book-template/vrryhtsjvrdz

[image: Image 1 : Desired Structure]

Here's a sample page from the book for reference.

[image: Image 2 : Sample Page]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton! Any suggestions on how to get this done?

Comment: Sadly. I can't come up with anything quickly.  I know that fixed divisions of pages have been implemented, and once described in a talk at a TUG meeting, but it appears that talk never made it into print.

Comment: No issues! Actually, this comment from a previous question seemed to work for me, even on the landscape page : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664408/299246. Thanks again! Also, I have an issue displaying line numbers inside the tikzfigure environment in the divisions, any suggestions there would be greatly appreciated : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692253/line-numbers-inside-a-tikz-environment.