# Line Numbers inside a Tikz Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, lineno

I'm trying to split my page into 4 subparts, similar to [How to split a page into four areas in tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664336/how-to-split-a-page-into-four-areas-in-tex). I wish to number the lines of text inside each of these parts, using the lineno package. But the numbers don't appear in the render. How do I display these line numbers inside this tikz environment?

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{quarterpage/.style={text width=.47*\textwidth, minimum height=.5*\textheight, 
    minimum width=.5*\textwidth, text depth=.47*\textheight}}

\newcommand{\posA}{($.5*(current page text area.north west)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posB}{($.5*(current page text area.north east)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posC}{($.5*(current page text area.south west)+.5*(current page text area)$)}
\newcommand{\posD}{($.5*(current page text area.south east)+.5*(current page text area)$)}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,outer=5cm,inner=2.5cm}
\setlength\columnsep{30pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[quarterpage]at\posA{
\begin{linenumbers}
one\\
two\\
three
\end{linenumbers}
};
\node[quarterpage]at\posB{B};
\node[quarterpage]at\posC{C};
\node[quarterpage]at\posD{D};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's what it looks like when compiled with XeLaTeX on Overleaf.

[image: Render]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos. I've replaced the code snippet with a MWE.

Comment: I'd look into something like `flowfram` rather than `tikz` here. As far as TeX is concerned, there are no lines inside a node. It's like expecting line numbers to work inside a multi-line cell of a `tabular`. There's nothing to number.

Comment: Actually, `tcolorbox` might be better. You can make extremely plain boxes, if that's what you want (they don't have to be fancy or coloured).

Comment: Thanks @cfr! would the implementation using flowfram/tcolorbox be similar to this? I haven't used those packages before.

Comment: I don't know. I'm just trying to think of something where you might be able to get proper lines. `tcolorbox` allows for line numbering code listings, I think. The documentation is a bit overwhelming until you work out you only need to look at the bits relevant to what you want to do - it is very modular. I've not used `flowfram` except to play with, but it allows you to split pages into frames. It is probably a more radical solution than `tcolorbox` so might not work if this is part of something bigger.

Comment: I'll try and look into it. Thanks!